# $location.path('/dashboard'); not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create simple login app in angular js

following is my login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AppName">
<head>
 <title></title>
    
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <form action="/" id="myLogin">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" ng-model="password"><br>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">login</button>

    </form>

</div>

 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and following is my controller.js

```js
var app = angular.module('AppName', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){

 $routeProvider
 .when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
 })
 .when('/dashboard', {
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
    })
    .otherwise({

     redirectTo: '/'
    });

});

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location){

 $scope.submit = function(){

  var uname = $scope.username;
  var password = $scope.password;

  if ($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin') {

   $location.path('/dashboard');
   console.log($location.path());
  }
  else
   {
    alert('wrong password');
   }

   


 };

});
```

but after submitting it is not redirecting to dashboard.html. in console it is showing path as /dashboard only. i am new to angular.js.

Comment: `.when('/dashboard', { templateUrl: 'dashboard.html', controller: 'loginCtrl' })`

Answer (score 0):

there isn't the view placeholder to being changed, you need a div with 
`<div ng-view></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location = "/dashboard";`

for loading your html templates you should use angular routing like below

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "login.htm"
    ,controller : "LoginController"
})
.when("/dashbord", {
    templateUrl : "dashbord.htm"
    ,controller : "DashbordController"
})

});
```